# WinForms, CheckedListbox Automatic column width

Tags: c#, winforms, checkedlistbox, column-width

I have a checkedlistbox with the property MultiColumn set to true.
I'm showing the control in two lines.

[image: My CheckedListbox]

Is there a way to automatically adjust the columns width to each set of columns (in a way that each set of columns will be in width which will show all texts in it)?
Or is it only possible to set the same width to all columns ?

Comment: Have you tried to set `AutoSizeColumnsMode` to `AllCells`?

Comment: there is no such property in checkedlistbox :(

Comment: In the datagridview :)

Comment: What datagridview? the question is about checkedlistbox! :|

Comment: CheckedListBox is not a flexible Multi Column control, Use a `TableLayoutPanel` with columns and rows that hosts `Checkboxes` or use a `DataGridView` with `CheckBoxColumns`

Comment: 10x :) for the answear

Comment: Sorry about misreading

Comment: never mind :) eventually the question was answered

Answer (score 4):

**On** setting to same column widths,

```
someCheckedListBox.ColumnWidth = 80;
```

Which `System.Windows.Forms.CheckedListBox`
inherited from `System.Windows.Forms.ListBox`

[image]

Comment: Your answear gives the same width to all sown columns. That was my starting point, i asked for option to set each column automaticly to the content width of that column.